# Maven2 & Groovy compilation error but not within Eclipse

Tags: maven-2, groovy

He,

I am having a mixed Java / Groovy eclipse project.

Inside eclipse utilizing the groovy plugin everything compiles just fine. In addition I have set up my project to utilize Maven2. And still everything compiles and runs (tests) just fine within eclipse.

However, compiling the project outside eclipse, i.e. using Maven2 standalone gives me compiler errors! The project is devided into several sub-projects (parent / module). The Maven2 configuration seems to be OK cause some of the modules compile but actually one gives me an compiler error, like:

```
[ERROR] \Projects\X\rules\src\main\groovy\x\Normalizer.java:[18,25] normalize(java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>) in x.
x.util.RuleUtil cannot be applied to (java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>>)

[ERROR] \Projects\X\rules\src\main\groovy\x\Statistics.java:[70,67] inconvertible types
found   : capture#683 of ?
required: java.lang.String
```

Why is this code compiling within eclipse but not using standalone Maven2?

Thanks in advance,
 /nm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is a stub generation problem. GMaven creates Java stubs for your Groovy files to compile against the remaining Java files.  If your application is completely in Groovy, or there is no referencing from Java classes to Groovy classes, you can remove the `<goal>generateStubs</goal>` goal.

The Groovy-Eclipse compiler does not require stubs and so you are not seeing this issue inside of Eclipse.

If you do require cross referencing between Groovy and Java, I'd recommend using the groovy-eclipse-compiler plugin for maven.  More information is here:

http://contraptionsforprogramming.blogspot.com/2010/09/where-are-all-my-stubs.html

With this, you will be sure that your compilation inside Eclipse and outside works exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy Eclipse plugin uses the version of Groovy presents within the plugin folder of Eclipse (groovy-1.7.5).
Most probably, the version of Groovy referenced in your maven file is different. You can specify it thought in the gmaven-runtime:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <!-- <goal>generateTestStubs</goal> -->
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```